# Deploy Termius software with Active Directory Group Policy, which includes pre-login settings using a shared account

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I want to deploy Termius software with Active Directory's Group Policy.

The software requires pre-login settings using a shared account.

How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

The Software Installation feature allows you to do one thing: specify the MSI installation file and switches. Any customizations need to occur in the MSI file.

For installations more involved, most organizations use an Configuration Management solution.